# Set X2Go up to allow remote windows on the local desktop?

Tags: x11, ssh-tunneling, nx, x2go

If I run `ssh -X server lxterminal` I get a new terminal window open on my local desktop that I can then launch new applications on the server from (similarly to the old `xrsh` application, except using a secure tunnel so I don't have to be on the same trusted LAN).  I have X2Go server installed on the same server, and the client on my local machine, but when I use it it runs a window manager on the remote server and creates a top-level window to contain all the windows created.  How can I configure it to behave the same as just using `ssh -X`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is called *application mode* in X2Go. In your session configuration just select `application` and `lxterminal` as the program to run.